# wxWidgets 2.8 to wxWidgets 2.9: wxLocale problems

Tags: wxwidgets

I do some transfer work coping with some code written with wxWidgets 2.8, now need transfer to wxWidgets 2.9.

I defined that:

```
wxLocale m_locale;
```

and use

```
m_locale.Init(iLocale, wxLOCALE_CONV_ENCODING)
```

(here iLocale is an int with value 58).

Now wx tells me that:

....\src\common\intl.cpp(361): assert "!(flags & wxLOCALE_CONV_ENCODING)" 
failed in wxLocale::Init(): wxLOCALE_CONV_ENCODING is no longer supported, add charset to your catalogs

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

wxLOCALE_CONV_ENCODING seems to be deprecated. Try to omit this flag (just don't use it).
I had the same problem when I was upgrading my wxwidgets version (2.8 to 3.0) and it worked.